# Notepad ++ How to remove most of the characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

Before :

> EMAIL|TEXT:7a
>   EMAIL|TEXT:4a
>   EMAIL|TEXT:8f
>   EMAIL|TEXT:34

After :

> EMAIL|TEXT
>   EMAIL|TEXT
>   EMAIL|TEXT
>   EMAIL|TEXT

how do I remove the code after the code `:` in the notepad ++

Answer (score 1):

```
:.*$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/27

Comment: Note that this will replace the colon as well (which is probably what the OP wanted), not just the text *after* it.

Answer (score 0):

I try this.

```
(:(?:(?!EMAIL|TEXT).)*)
```

replace with empty.

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/bY4lZ7/1

Answer (score -1):

1.Cntrl+F
2. Go to replace tab
3. Select search mode as "regular expression"
4. Replace :.*$ with empty string

Answer (score -2):

use :.*$

use :.*$ for edit and set check boxes as given

Comment: This is identical to @vks answer.